# Can I ssh into my account without invoking .profile?

Tags: ssh, .profile

I want to ssh into my account, but I don't want the current version of my .profile login script to be executed.  Is there a way to log in without running .profile?

*(Disclaimer: I found a work-around which I posted below, but I wonder if there's a better answer)*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can run the followin command:

```
ssh -t user@host bash --noprofile
```

where `-t` option to `ssh` is to force *tty* allocation.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me log into my server which had a full disk. Took me a while to realize my .bashrc may have been triggering disk writes.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
scp me@machine:.profile .
# Fix .profile
scp .profile me@machine:.
ssh me@machine
```

Answer (score 3):

To permanently avoid trouble, in my `.bashrc` on the target system, I have:

```
if [ -z "$SSH_CLIENT" ] ; then  
...
fi
```

surrounding ssh-incompatible stuff. `SSH_CLIENT` is defined for shells invoked via ssh, and not for other shells.

```
ssh user@somewhere "env >env.ssh"
```

walk over so `somewhere`, login as `user`, and:

```
env >env.local
diff env.local env.ssh
```